# Ошибка подключения приложения к mysql / GO

Tags: mysql, sql-server, golang

Разрабатываю софт для парсинга баз данных mysql, столкнулся с ошибкой при использовании github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql. При запуске софта на Windows Server 2016 вылазит такая ошибка:

```
[mysql] 2024/02/19 05:28:57 packets.go:36: read tcp 127.0.0.1:52891->127.0.0.1:1433: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
[mysql] 2024/02/19 05:30:57 packets.go:36: read tcp 127.0.0.1:52923->127.0.0.1:1433: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Error pinging database: driver: bad connection
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: "Удалённый хост принудительно закрыл соединение." Может на той стороне какие-то логи есть?

Comment: @CrazyElf, это и есть логи с той стороны)

Comment: А, торможу. А на стороне `Go` что говорит? )

Comment: порт корректно указан в настройках подключения? 1433 для ms sql  используется обычно, а драйвер у вас под mysql